# spring-cloud-stream kafka avro

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Is there any support for or plan to support avro and/or the schema registry from the confluent platform in spring-cloud-stream? I see that there are dependencies on avro in spring-integration-kafka 1.3.0.RELEASE which is being excluded from spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, but the master branch of spring-integration-kafka (2.0) and spring-kafka don't have any avro dependency that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

We do intend to support Avro and other formats, as well as schema registry and evolution. There is an open issue you can follow here:https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/512

For now, this can be done in a more complicated way by using Codecs and/or MessageConverters, for example here: https://github.com/viniciusccarvalho/schema-evolution-samples (which serves as the POC for the former). The example is a little bit more elaborate as it aims to support schema evolution, but it is possible to register a Codec that uses Avro (instead of the Kryo default).